# Finding job on Visit visa

Tags: visas, schengen, indian-citizens, work, middle-east

Can Indian Citizens find job in the middlle east or schengen Countries on Visit visa/Tourist visa? 
Is it permissible or not?

Answer (score 2):

You are free to *search* for a job in the Middle East on a <strike>tourist</strike> non-employment visa.

However, you cannot be employed on that visa.  This is highly illegal and there are serious repercussions for both you and your employer.

If you are on a visit visa and you happen to be offered employment, you have to leave the country and come back on a suitable visa in order for you to legally work.

The type of visa you will need will depend on your employer (if its government, private sector, or under a government contract to a private sector company) and how you are hired (directly, contract, though a government manpower agency, etc).

For schengen countries, the policy varies per member state.  Generally speaking, only Annex II state citizens are allowed to work during their visa-free stay. However, beyond that stay, they are also required to obtain the correct visa.

India is an Annex I state, which means unfortunately this does not apply to you.

However for seeking employment there are no specific restrictions that I have been able to find.

The wikipedia listing on the [visa policy of the schengen area](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_policy_of_the_Schengen_Area) has some excellent information in this regard.

However in all cases you cannot be permanently employed unless you are admitted into the country on a visa that indicates your eligibility for employment in the country; and to do this you will have to exit and re-enter.

Comment: Is there any difference in the salary pay if employed on their country and hiring fron overseas?

Comment: The salary will depend on your position; but the benefits for foreign workers vary greatly between government and private sector.

Comment: And what about the schengen?

Comment: The comments are not for discussion, please either join the chat or ask another specific question.

Comment: I have already asked for both the middle east and schengen in the question.

Comment: I am not discussing i m clarifying it.

Comment: Please edit your original question to add any clarifying information or additional questions.